# Wordpress, adding Admin-Menu Items

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, menu

I'm using this tutorial (http://projects.tareq.co/wp-generator/index.php) and its creator to generate a WordPress CRUD administration. The problem, however, already arises at the point where I'm adding the new menu button. The code says

```
add_action('init', 'init_conference');

function init_conference () {
        include(dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/class-conference-events-admin-menu.php');

        $menu_dgvs = new Conference_Events_Admin_Menu();
}
```

Which seems to call the corresponant __construct in that class:

```
class Conference_Events_Admin_Menu {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'admin_menu' ) );
    }

    public function admin_menu() {
        // menu that does work
        add_menu_page(__('Watu PRO', 'watupro'), __('Watu PRO', 'watupro'), WATUPRO_MANAGE_CAPS, "watupro_exams", 'watupro_exams');

        // menu that does not work
        add_menu_page( __( 'Konferenz', '' ), __( 'Konferenz', '' ), '', 'conference', array( $this, 'plugin_page' ), 'dashicons-groups', null );

        add_submenu_page( 'conference', __( 'Konferenz', '' ), __( 'Konferenz', '' ), '', 'conference', array( $this, 'plugin_page' ) );

    }

    // here's some more code that has nothing to do with the menu
}
```

The first add_menu_page() is copied over from another plugin, it is shown as it should. The second is copied from the generator. It shows nothing, as if these calls weren't present.

What am I getting wrong here? I can't find a difference between the add_menu call from the other plugin and the generated one from the generator.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Work on a problem for 5 hours, no solution, post to stackoverflow => solution found: it was the capabilities field. 'manage_options' in parameter 3 and everything works.